# Typing anonymous objects in Typescript without using type assertions

Tags: typescript

Consider:

```
type Foo = {
   bar: string,
   baz: number
}

const bars = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const foos = bars.map<Foo>((bar, i) => {
   return {
     bar,
     baz: i
   }
});
```

This this will *not* enforce the exact type of the return value from the map, e.g. I can say

```
return {
  bar,
  baz: i,
  extraProp: 'boo!'    // this works! (bad - i want this to fail)
}
```

and it will work fine. This works the same as if I didn't use a generic type and used a type assertion on the return value:

```
return {
  bar,
  baz: i,
  extraProp: 'boo!'   // works (bad)
} as Foo
```

The only way I can figure out to get the actual type to be enforced completely is creating a temporary variable:

```
const returnVal: Foo = {
  bar,
  baz: i,
  // extraProp: 'boo!' // won't work - good! typescript prevented a bug!
}
return returnVal;
```

Is there any syntax that permits creating an anonymous object such as in the `return` statement that would allow enforcement of the type completely, rather than just a type assertion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that object literals are checked for extra properties only when they are directly assigned to a parameter/variable/return value. While you do specify the type parameter on `map` the arrow function will first be typed first with this signature:

```
(bar: string , i: number) => {    
    bar: string,
    baz: number,
    extraProp: string
}
```

And then this function is checked for compatibility with the argument of map (typed as `(bar: string , i: number) => Foo`) and will be found to be compatible.

A simple work around would be to specify the type not on `map` but the return type of the arrow function :

```
const foos = bars.map((bar, i): Foo => {
    return {
        bar,
        baz: i,
        extra: "" // error here, as expected
    }
});
```

This is not a type assertion, but you do need to specify the type, but you do so on `map` anyway, so the amount of typing is about the same.

Comment: Yes and No. This did not work during my testing, at least not without errors. Since you declare specifically what the object should and should not hold and do (i.e. The Foo-Class), any additional parameters you assign will cause the app to throw up errors during compilation (Specifically: 'Object literal may only specify known properties'). This was the Route Google decided on when going for static types (not sure if this is actually based on Angular or TypeScript). It means you have adhere to more rules, but also that JavaScript's 'anything goes' is a thing of the past. A worthy trade off IMO

Comment: Even further, the entire point of anonymous types is that they are, well, anonymous. You don't assign a Foo-Class in the First Place because you want to return whatever you feel like. This gets rid of the rules imposed upon you, at a risk. Personally, I work with a whole bunch of 'Model'-Classes that are merely POCO's so I can inform a Method or Arrow-Function the exact response of what I want back from it, thus allowing the kind of 'Return-Statement' you have mentioned, but only that and nothing more.

Comment: @DeuxAlpha What that intended for me ? Because it does not make sense in context ..

Comment: Partially, although I did go on a bit of a ramble, didn't I? My main point was that you assigned an 'extra'-property to the 'Foo'-Class, which originally only held two properties (bar and baz). You'd have to specifically declare 'extra' to be part of the Foo-Class in order to avoid errors.

Comment: @DeuxAlpha The question was about an error that the user was expecting but was not getting, he wants an error when returning extra properties. He tried specifying the type on `map` but that still did not yield the error. My point was that specifying the type on the arrow function will result in the expected error. I edited the post to make it more clear taht the error is there and expected

Comment: You are perfectly correct, my mistake. I understood the question the exact opposite way, meaning that he was looking for a way to add parameters to a class he'd already declared (without causing errors). Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - didn't think of typing the callback signature! Thanks!

Comment: @DeuxAlpha re-reading my question - not at all surprised you read it backwards, I tried to clarify for future readers.